# How do I represent an android fragment in UML?

Tags: java, android, uml

Just wondering what the best way to represent an activity with a few fragments in UML or more specifically a Class Diagram.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you: [ http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/07/android-uml-design-app-part-1.html?m=1][1]

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me - I had spotted that but it didn't mention fragments specifically so I thought I would ask on here as well.

Not having much luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the point of view.

The most thorough analysis of fragments can be done by Object diagram or Composite Structure Diagram.

If you want to model their outer behaviour, Component diagram or any of behavioral diagrams will do.